# What's an adjective/phrase for "as a matter of principle"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Looking for a single-word adjective or phrase meaning "on principle" or "as a matter of principle", that can fit in:

> I don't go on dates with people I just met. That's why I declined to go on a date with him, even if he was cute. I gave him a [?] rejection.

> I'd love to do that, but I have to give you a [?] refusal; it'd be against my moral code.

Close, but not quite:

- "principled" feels like it means "ethical". But my refusal isn't a matter of ethics, but a matter of convention.
- "conventional" or "traditional" imply regularity. This could be the first time I'm making this kind of refusal, and it could still be a matter of principle.

Comment: I can write an answer for *pro forma* or *across-the-board*.

Comment: pro forma is good enough; i'll edit it to a phrase request

Comment: I was wondering how it could be both "a matter of convention" and "the first time I'm making this refusal" - to me, convention implies something that is done repeatedly in the same way - but *pro forma* seems as good as you'll get, although it has strong implications of convention or rote.

Comment: Not convinced that any of the alternatives suggested are an improvement in the context suggested (likewise the "categorical" in the answer suggested). All of them lose important shades of meaning and are less idiomatic.

Comment: If the two words *pro forma* are an acceptable answer why not the obvious *on principle*?  The principle in question may simply be not dating people you only met 10 minutes ago, it doesn't have to be a "moral" principle, it might be a hygienic principle or a financial principle or any other sort of principle.

Comment: The idiomatic way to phrase both your use cases would be to use _on principle_. We generally don’t ‘give refusals/rejections’ nearly as often as we simply ‘refuse/reject’ (or ‘turn down’), which also negates the need for the phrase you’re looking for to be adjectival: “I turned him down on principle” and “I have to refuse your offer on principle”. (Also, your second example doesn’t make sense. If someone is against your moral code, it’s not something you’d love to do – it’s something you’d feel uncomfortable doing.)

Comment: *Conventional* and *traditional* are not apt for what you have in mind not only because they imply regularity (over time), but also because they imply that the policy is shared by people in the relevant community, while in the first example the rejection is based on the individual's own policy (without regard to whether it is shared by others).

Answer (score 9):

**Categorical** could work here. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/categorical) defines it as

> 1
> : absolute, unqualified
>
> > a categorical denial

The idea here is that a principled objection or denial occurs without caveat or exception. *Categorical* describes the absolute state of that objection.

Comment: +1 This is a strong answer, even if it is a little more sophisticated in its tone. To categorically reject dates means to reject them based on rules and qualification of members of categories which is exactly what happens when one applies heuristics to dating. "I'd love to do that, but I have to give you a categorical refusal; it'd be against my moral code. It's not a personal decision, but a principled one." You can also rephrase this as "While I don't want to refuse, I have to refuse on principle; it'd be against my moral code. Sometimes we must categorically reject action."

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *blanket* would work — that would “cover” any reasons you had for the rejection.

> **blanket**, *n.* and *adj.*
> **B.** *adj.* (in attributive use).
> **4.** Originally *U.S.* Covering or including all or many cases, contingencies, situations, etc.; inclusive; all-embracing.
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

> *I don’t go on dates with people I just met. That’s why I declined to go on a date with him, even if he was cute. I gave him a blanket
> rejection.*
>
> *I’d love to do that, but I have to give you a blanket refusal; it’d be against my moral code.*

Comment: *Blanket*, as used in, say, *blanket policy*, does convey the idea that the OP has in mind, but I don't think that it works syntactically in the OP's examples. I may have a blanket policy to decline invitations in all such cases, and I may decline a particular invitation as a result of that blanket policy, but I don't think one would say that this particular rejection is a blanket rejection.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

> I gave him the **standard** rejection.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/standard) has

- a moral rule that should be obeyed

---

Similarly

> I gave him the **customary** refusal.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/customary) has

- reflecting or showing a way of behaving or a belief that has been established for a long time among a group of people:

Comment: And other synonyms, such as **obligatory**.

Comment: Somehow "standard" and "customary" both sound extremely derogatory here, because they can both be understood as synonyms of "usual, normal, not special, unexceptional". *"He asked me to go on a data and I dismissed him with the standard rejection, without giving it a second thought, because he was so ordinary and so not special"*

Comment: Neither of those sound like typical usage.

Comment: @Stef the OP hasn't asked for a word that you use to decline a date. You have written an irrelevant rejoinder, quite unlike what OP is saying.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am sure there is no need for that kind of hostile comment, thank you. Have a nice day.

Comment: As the quoted definition says, something is customary if 'has been established for a long time among a group of people'. The OP, however, seems to want a term that includes the principles that a particular individual adopts without regard to whether they are shared by other people.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a word or standard phrase that does exactly what you want. Even "as a matter of principle" carries the "ethical" connotation that you are trying to avoid. I think for the first example you might convey what you want by adding the sentence "There was nothing personal about it." But obviously that's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason is to follow your rule, then consider

> ... I gave him my ***mandatory*** rejection.

It is another synonym of *obligatory*:

> **1**
> : required by a law or rule : OBLIGATORY
>      *the **mandatory** retirement age*
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mandatory)</sub>

---

If instead you want to convey you have personal principles that prevent you from doing what others might view as customary, you could consider

> ... I gave him a ***conscientious*** rejection.

This is kind of a pun on the term ***conscientious objection***:

> the fact of refusing to obey a particular order or rule or to do a particular type of work for moral or religious reasons
> <sub>[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/conscientious-objection)</sub>

While the word itself just means following your *conscience*:

> **2**
> : governed by or conforming to the dictates of conscience : SCRUPULOUS
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscientious)</sub>